# Disabling compression for third-party JS libraries

Tags: extjs

I am using Sencha Cmd v7.3.0.19 and Ext JS 7.2. I have some third party libraries which I do not include in the bundle. So they are only copied during the build. But when they are copied, they are also compressed, which is what I don't want. I want them to be copied as they are.
[image]

How can I disable compression for third-party JS libraries?

Thanks,

Ipek

Comment: Try to use "includeInBundle": false, or "remote": true properties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @ArthurRubens, however, when `remote: true` files are not copied into the build folder, and this is not what I want: I want them to be copied but not to be compressed. `includeInBundle: false` is the default setting, and it is to concatenate the file to the output container JS file.

Comment: Do you want to concatenate them without minimizing?

Comment: I do not want to concatenate them: I just want them to be copied into the build folder as JS assets, as they are.

Comment: Hm.. why don‘t you copy them manually? 

Comment: I don't want to deal with manually copying them to build folder. Isn't this `sencha app build -production` for? It produces an output of our app code and copies necessary assets and resources to the build folder.

Comment: Ok, the you can register your js as resource and at the same time as external js which will point to resources js path.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of @ArthurRubens, I realized that I had to put my JS assets, the ones that I do not want to be bundled or compressed, into the `resources` folder. By doing that, they are copied as they are to the build output folder.

After that, I have also added the JS resources to the "list of JavaScript assets" section in the `app.json` file, but this time with `remote: true`, so that they are just referenced, not being copied.

[image: List of all JavaScript assets section in app.json]

Comment: I'm a little confused... in your screenshot, it's `remote: true`, but in your post, you said `remote: false`... is the image typo'd?

Comment: Oh, yes :( It should be `remote: true` to make them not copied but referenced as JS sources. Thanks for the correction @incutonez.

Comment: All righty, I edited the post to reflect that.  Thanks for clarifying!